# Call type method return exception

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string which holds some words that i will be changing later by my methods : 
example :

```
Hello $name How are you doing ? 
i'm $ask
```

i will be changing $name and $ask using a method :

```
    public static string ReturnLetter<T>(Dictionary<string, T> value)
    {
        var letter = File.ReadAllText("LETTER.html");
        var newletter = "";
        foreach (var type in value)
        {
            var item = type.Value;
            var newstring = item.GetType().GetMethod("ReturnValue").Invoke(null, new object[] { }).ToString();
            newletter = letter.Replace(type.Key, newstring);
        }
        return newletter;
    }
```

i'm returning the Dictionary values with :

```
    public static Dictionary<string, Type> returnDic()
    {
        var types = GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "ConsoleApplication11.Packets");
        var Dic = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
        foreach (var t in types)
        {
            Dic.Add(t.Name, t);
        }
        return Dic;
    }
```

Types i holds is :

```
class name
{
    private static string[] names =
    {
        "miri",
        "sara",
    };

    public static string ReturnValue()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        return names[random.Next(0, 1)];
    }
}
```

I'm getting exception (null references)   at

```
var newstring = item.GetType().GetMethod("ReturnValue").Invoke(null, new object[] { }).ToString();
```

i couldn't really track where the error is coming from ! 
i'm stuck at this for like an hour now

any help is appreciated

EDIT : 
in the method which works :

```
    public static string ReturnValue<T>() 
    {
        return typeof(T).GetMethod("ReturnValue").Invoke(null,new object[] { }).ToString();
    }
```

and then i realized that `item.GetType()` return RunTimeTime Instead of which typeof(T) returns .

Comment: Question seems to me like an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ;  [XY-Problem 2](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Try breaking up that statement into multiple statements and check the debugger at each point to see what's going on.

Comment: @HansKesting I tried to use the change method directly without passing the Dictionary and it works passing it only one class but when i pass all the classes as a dictionary it doesn't works and i v checked multiple times my classes and methods

Comment: @SimonWilson all my methods in the namespace's classes are statics as default bindingflag

Answer (score 0):

As `item` seems to be a `Type`, try replacing

```
item.GetType().GetMethod("ReturnValue")...
```

with

```
item.GetMethod("ReturnValue")...
```

You were trying to find that method on class `Type` instead of class `name`. As it doesn't exist there, you get a null.

But a better architecture would use instance methods and interfaces. No reflection needed to invoke methods then.

Comment: i'm using reflection cause i will be replacing more than 10+ words and that will result me more code lines and the item is T type because its value is `var item = type.Value;`

Comment: It was right but the item holds a Keypair value i had to take the value which is a Type and then get its methods with out getting its Type first since its an type already !

Answer (score 0):

I finally got to notice the issue !

in the method :

```
public static Dictionary<string, Type> returnDic()
{
    var types = GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "ConsoleApplication11.Packets");
    var Dic = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
    foreach (var t in types)
    {
        Dic.Add(t.Name, t);
    }
    return Dic;
}
```

I'm returning a **Type** and not a T type and in the Replace Method i'm getting the Type of Type

```
foreach (var type in value)
{
    var item = type.Value;
    var newstring = item.GetType().GetMethod("ReturnValue").Invoke(null, new object[] { }).ToString(); ////// GetType() of Type
    newletter = letter.Replace(type.Key, newstring);
}
```

i solved it by simple Converting `type.Value` to Type

```
var item = type.Value as Type;
```